# Image dissapears when using a href

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

**JS**

```
$(function(){
   $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
      setInterval(function(){
   $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
      .next('img').fadeIn(1000)
      .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
    5000); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="fadein"> 
<img src="IMG 1..">
<img src="IMG 2..">
/div>
```

This works fine but the moment when I add

```
<a href="LINK" target="_blank"><img src="IMG 3..."></a>
```

The IMG 3... dissapears for some reason ? 
Could anyone explain why and provide me a solution for it ?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that "doesn't work"

Comment: Wrong selectors, inspect code (check HTML in developer tools) and you will see what's happening (first child in one moment is a element, that causing problems)... http://jsfiddle.net/kx7v7fda/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dethariel/m36807hL/).

The problem is that

```
$('.fadein :first-child')
```

takes **all** [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) nodes, which is also your `IMG3` node (it's the first child of an `a` element). To fix this, I added a direct [child selector `>`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), thus making it look like:

```
$(function () {
    $('.fadein >:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein >:first-child').fadeOut(1000)
            .next().fadeIn(1000)
            .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    },
    5000);
});
```

Please, note, that the first selector has also changed from the initial, because otherwise your `a` element will be shown, but it will show nothing, as the `img` element was hidden by the second line.

Comment: This solved the link problem, but an additional problem appeared. 
When the first fades have been, it shows the first for a very short period 

View : http://www.camerabeveiligingspecialist.nl/

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `</div>`  ("<" is missing)

Comment: But that '*works fine*', so I suspect that's typo posting the code here, not the problem in the original.